# Banding with intel HD 4000

Tags: intel-graphics, mac, intel, macbook-pro

I just installed 12.10 on a mid-2012 13" Macbook Pro and I've noticed that gradients on-screen exhibit slight banding problems.  The system says it's running 24-bit colour but it seems more like 16-bit.

How should I go about troubleshooting this?  Is it the kernel?  Intel gfx drivers?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

From https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/ICC_Profiles I managed to find the default icc profile in OSX and use xcalib to load it.

e.g.
    /usr/bin/xcalib -d :0 /home/username/icc/Color LCD-00000610-0000-9CC7-0000-0000042731C0.icc

For some reason, when I run that from command-line I need to restart X (I just suspend to RAM and wake it again) before I notice the changes.

Comment: Turns out xcalib wasn't doing anything.  I removed xcalib, rebooted and suspended the machine and the colour profile was fixed.  SO, there's something about suspending the machine that gets the colour profile on the right track...